# Apple in-app-purchase bug in iOS 11.1.2

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

hope this question is acceptable here.

I am running couple apps on the App Store and lately there have been user contacting me with the same issue. When they purchase the "Premium-version" on my apps, the app won't update to Premium. And when they try to "Restore the purchase" they just get a never ending spinning wheel (`UIActivityIndicator`).

I really suspect this to be an issue with iOS 11.1.2. Because users has updated their iOS and then restored the purchase just fine.

Has anybody else noticed this issue? Could it possibly be related to iOS 11.1.2?

Comment: *"... there have been user contacting me ..."* Have you tested it, and it's working for you but not your users?

Comment: Exactly, it's working for me, and I have loads of people buying the premium version, we are talking thousands, and there has only been 4 people contacting me so far with this issues, but they all have the same problem. Seems odd, why would so few get this specific problem. And also, I have had apps with the same payment system for more than two years, and these problems have only been occuring from 12.25.2017-today.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same issues. Tell your users to either upgrade their system or in-App purchase will not work.

Comment: The problem is now I have users having the same issue in iOS 11.3